# Affordable path to getting a degree online related to web dev?

Tags: education, continuing-education

I have a lot of skills in web development but without having a degree it's been difficult to get a web dev job. Pretty sure I've got a ceiling in my current job making about 50k (basically a data analyst, but without the title or full pay)

Trying to come up with a plan that will leave me with a degree from an at least semi-respectable university with annual tuition of $5K or less... Need to be able to do it online so I can continue working my current job. Not sure if this is possible or where to start.

I appreciate any tips you can provide! My location is in the US, KC area

Comment: I feel this is a bit broad for the workplace and will change over time. I could list several universities online that could do the course in the price range, but it gets all rather opinionated and won't really be useful for future readers.

Comment: Also, you location will change the answers as some countries are more open than others for online certification.

Comment: I recommend looking at universities near you to see if they do a cheap long distance course that you can do.

Comment: @Meerfallthedewott Please don't post answers in comments, it will be deleted. OP: what is your work experience, how many years at each position? Did you go to college/ how long ago?

Comment: I would recommend creating a portfolio or website to show off your web development skills. A lot of places hiring developers want actual proof that you are a capable developer.

Answer (score 1):

As a dad with a kid approaching high school, I'm starting to put my antennae up on college options and their current costs. There seem to be a gazillion schools out there offering online coursework these days. Affordable is more difficult to find, unfortunately.

One route would be to start at a community college. These are usually much less expensive than full 4 year programs. Still, the instruction is usually just as good for the level of classes you would be taking there - sometimes better in my experience (and I took several CC courses myself to pick up subjects I didn't know), as the professors aren't splitting their attention between research (or writing research proposals) and teaching. Completing an Associate's degree at a CC might help you raise that salary ceiling you are trying to get through and should give you a transcript with introductory and core classes that you could transfer to a four year school to finish the last couple years of a Bachelor's degree.

Additionally, I did a web search using the terms "affordable degree web development". Several lists of (relatively) inexpensive programs came up. I looked through three of the lists, but not many had schools that were at or below the cost you mentioned; some didn't have any, even for a school that appeared on other lists (i.e. the lists sometimes showed different prices for the same school, even when they were claiming to be for the same year). One school that came up in all the lists I looked at was [Brigham Young University - Idaho Online](http://www.byui.edu/online). Another that came up was [Fort Hays State University Virtual College](https://www.fhsu.edu/virtualcollege/index). These may or may not come in at the cost you want, it's not clear to me, but I think it's up to you to investigate more fully.

Finally, I recommend that you investigate financial aid and tuition reimbursement resources that may be available to you. Colleges sometimes have relatively unknown scholarships (sometimes with weird requirements) for which you may qualify. Membership in some organizations - social, professional, religious, etc. - can help you get reduced tuition or a scholarship. Also, employers will often pay at least part of the cost for employees who are degree seeking, in hopes of getting employees with more skills and loyalty. Personally, I obtained a Master's Degree via night school using a tuition reimbursement plan at my employer (I paid for each class up front and they paid me back as long as I got an A or B grade; books and other fees were my responsibility, but relatively low, compared to tuition).

Comment: There's also https://www.coursera.org/degrees/bachelor-of-science-computer-science-london, which is fully online. It's a mostly flat amount, which is above OP's budget for 3 years, but under for 4 or more years.